# Cocos2d/Inkscape image help

Tags: image, cocos2d-iphone, png, inkscape

I have an image (CCSprite) in my app. I created the image in Inkscape, and exported it as a PNG. I then went to Preview (I have a Mac) and I used Alpha and got rid of the white around the edges. I then import it to my project, and add it to the layer. When I have a black background, there is still white around the edges, and makes the image look very crappy. I go to Preview again, and there is NO white around the edges! Am I missing something? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting:

Document Properties > Page > Background and check the aplpha channel (A). On RGB tab set all values to 255, including A.

What size of export are you making.  When you export, there should be no background and no white edges if the setting above is correct and you don't have a white edges in your project (look at Inkscapes tracing function to get rid of white outlines if you do).  If there are white outlines just in the exported PNG, it could be an artifact from trying to scale your image down to an extremely small size.  Normally though, there shouldn't be any outlines and the step you're doing where you open the file in Preview and adjust the Alpha shouldn't be necessary.  BTW, using Preview to adjust the alpha may be causing the extra problem of a black background.

I have many CCSprites using PNGs I eported from Inkscape.  After exporting once and adding them to my project (with the "copy" option checked to copy to my resources folder), when I make changes, I simply perform an export to the file in the resources folder and the images are updated within my project without any extra steps.  Try the same same workflow and see if that fixes the problem.